# Compositions - Fruit Salad

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm asked to find $s(n)$ which is the number of ways to make a fruit salad with $n$ pieces of fruit, given that we must use strawberries by the half-dozen, an odd number of apples, between *2* and *7* bananas and at most *1* pineapple.

I started evaluating the ordinary generating function $S(X)$. I found

$$S(X)=\frac{1}{1-x^6}\frac{x}{1-x^2}\frac{x^2-x^8}{1-x}(1+x)=\frac{1}{1-x^6}\frac{x}{1-x}\frac{x^2-x^8}{1-x}$$

However, I don't manage to find a closed formula for $s(n)$ after. I know that I'm supposed to "evalute $S(X)$ at $x^n$" but I don't really understand how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at this fundamental page to write in $MathJax$: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:
\begin{align}
S(z) &= \frac{1}{1 - z^6} \frac{z}{1 - z^2} \frac{z^2 - z^8}{1 - z} (1 + z) \\
     &= \frac{1}{1 - z^6} \frac{z}{(1 - z) (1 + z)} 
           \frac{z^2 (1 - z^6)}{1 - z} (1 + z) \\
     &= \frac{z^3}{(1 - z)^2} \\
     &= z^3 \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-2}{k} (-1)^k z^k \\
     &= z^3 \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 1}{1} z^k \\
     &= z^3 \sum_{k \ge 0} (k + 1) z^k
\end{align}
I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @User2014, it wasn't *so* hard. In such cases look if you can group factors and simplify.